# How better to adjust more than 2 keyboard layouts

Tags: keyboard-layout

From time to time I have to use characters not present in my two layouts: Latin and Cyrillic and instead of digging in Character Map I thought to add 2 additional keyboard layouts.

My issue with this approach is that most of the time I use just two layouts, and while changing to different layout (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>) I now have to press couple of times to switch to previous layout. It's not just number of pressings, but I have to press two keys at once and track keyboard indicator which is distracting.

I tried some options presented in keyboard settings, but I think there is no option that I would like - change just between first two layouts on <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, and if I want to use additional layout I can choose it from keyboard indicator drop-down menu.

Any ideas how this might be possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

my approach towards this problem would be assigning a combination of keys (via keyboard shortcuts) for either using [`loadkeys`](http://how-to.wikia.com/wiki/Howto_change_the_keyboard_layout_in_text_mode_on_a_linux-based_operating_system)/[`setxkbmap`](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1551403). Although, you might want to revert back to last used layout after using 'the special one', thus you might need to write a bash script for that.

Comment: This is a much better method than my suggestion, i wasn't aware of those commands. I would use this method and assign a different keyboard shortcut to each.

Comment: I'm using setxkbmap with Awesome Window Manager to switch between 4 different layouts - I've mapped them to Ctrl+Shift+{1,2,3,4} and can switch to any of the layouts with just one chord. So, +1 to @shookees's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Would it be possible to use the IBus keyboard instead? IBus can have multiple layouts added, but is generally just toggled on and off using Ctrl-Space. This toggles between the system keyboard layout and the currently selected ibus keyboard, rather than rotating through everything.

To test this, I think you'd need to:

- Removed the current extra keyboard layouts added using "Keyboard Layout" and leave only your default keyboard. Verify that the standard XKB keyboard indicator icon is gone.
- Add the package **ibus-m17n**
- Run **Keyboard Input Methods** to start IBus

Go to IBus icon > Preferences  then select and add input methods needed.

Use Ctrl + Space to enable/disable IBus and Alt + Left Shift to change IBus keyboards. These keyboard shortcuts can be change to whatever you like, including a single key.

You might want to test in a virtual machine first.