# How can I assign hotkey for a keyboard layout?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

How can I assign hotkey for a keyboard layout, as showed on screenshot from windows ?

I want to turn on Turkish on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> and Tatar on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>

[image]

Comment: I'm linking [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/122174/how-to-better-adjust-more-then-2-keyboard-layouts) as related